# Is there a way to specify a dynamic report filename in TestCafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, report, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am writing the output of my TestCafe to file. I was wondering if it can be a dynamic path like a screenshot path.

I tried using something like the values listed here, but I think this is only for screenshots and videos.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/screenshots-and-videos.html#path-pattern-placeholders

Here is what works, but is just not dynamic:

```
testcafe chrome test.testcafe -r json:report.json
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
testcafe chrome test.testcafe -r json:T:\Logs\ -p ${DATE}/${TIME}/${FIXTURE}/${TEST}/${FILE_INDEX}.json
```

EDIT 1: Should have said this, but I am using TestCafe Studio.  I can use the built-in Function action, but I'm stuck with the limited functionality of Studio.

Comment: Answer is not the answer I wanted but does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the [programming interface](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/) to customize your [reporter](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/runner.html#reporter) output:

**run.js**:

```js
const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
let testcafe         = null;

createTestCafe('localhost', 1337, 1338)
    .then(tc => {
        testcafe     = tc;
        const runner = testcafe.createRunner();

        const config = { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }; // you can specify it as a date, etc.

        return runner
            .src(['d:/***/test.js'])
            .browsers(['chrome'])
            .reporter('xunit', `reports/${config.key1}/out-${config.key2}.xml`)
            .run();
    })
    .then(failedCount => {
        console.log('Tests failed: ' + failedCount);
        testcafe.close();
    });
```

Command:

```
node run.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm however looking for a solution to add as an argument.  I'm using TestCafe Studio and can't do what you suggested however.  I am trying to use the [Configuration](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/configuration-file.html) file they suggest to use

Answer (score 2):

Currently, TestCafe Studio does not allow customizing a report name. We will consider your suggestion for our future releases.

As a workaround, I recommend you take a look at the [Export the Report](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400187/user-interface/report-view#export-the-report) functionality